# Seleccionar item automáticamente en ListView

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

Buenas tardes.
En mi proyecto utilizo un Spinner que pasa por **setOnItemSelectedListener();** en el onCreate, el cual selecciona el primer item automáticamente y lo muestra en pantalla para mi caso. Sin embargo para el ListView no causa el mismo efecto, el **setOnItemClickListener()** que utilizo para el ListView no reacciona hasta que yo mismo haga la selección del item en la lista. He intentado utilizar **setOnItemSelectedListener();** pero no reacciona ni siquiera cuando quiero seleccionar un item.

Comparto parte de mi código que es bastante simple.

```
   adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, miLista);
    listLineas.setAdapter(adaptador);

listLineas.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        ...
    }
    });
```

Gracias.

Comment: Que deseas realizar en tu ListView cuando inicia?

Comment: Muestro una lista de coordenadas en un mapa, el listview contiene el nombre de cada lista. Es por eso que al momento de iniciar mi actividad, quiero que el listview ya tenga seleccionado el primer item y muestre lo correspondiente en pantalla.

Answer (score 1):

Para seleccionar el primer ítem de tu listview esto debería de funcionarte:

```
listLineas.setSelection(0);
```

Luego dentro del listener puedes hacer comprobar si el hay un item seleccionado, si es asi hacer lo que necesites:

```
    listLineas.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if(selectedItem == 0){
            //Haz los que necesites..
        }else{
        }
    }
  });
```